# While creating an xml string in php, my script just seems to stop

Tags: php, xml, string, amazon-web-services

I am simply trying to create this string

```
$post_string ='<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
  <Header>
  <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
  <MerchantIdentifier>Outdoor_outlet_seller</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>true</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>' . rand(1,1000) . '</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
  <Product>
    <SKU>'. $product->getSKU() . error_log("Got sku of product" . $product->getSKU()).'</SKU>

    <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
    <LaunchDate>' . date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:sO') . '</LaunchDate>
  <DescriptionData>
    <Brand>'. $product->getBrand() . error_log($product->getBrand()) . '</Brand>
    <Description>' . $product->getDescription() . '</Description>
    <ItemType>Sports & Outdoors</ItemType>
  </DescriptionData>
    </Message>
  </AmazonEnvelope>';
```

For some reason, everything just stops when the script reaches the "Brand" line of the xml and I cannot find out why.  Has anyone here had a similar problem?  It would be fantastic if someone could help me out with this :) Thanks!

Comment: Is PHP's error reporting enabled? Do you see any errors?

Comment: PHP's error reporting is enabled but its not showing any errors which is another reason why im so confused by this.  Everything works before the brand tag, even if I put code before brand on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the node value its not in a valid xml format so go and tell xml not to parse the value ... Use cdata tags  `<Brand><![CDATA['. $product->getBrand() . error_log($product->getBrand()) . ']]></Brand>` ....

For reference you may want to read: [[w3schools on xml CDATA]](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Comment: I left the w3schools reference in when I fixed the tags, but you may want to consider removing it as those links have a tendency to get posts down-voted.

Comment: Yea it's not first time i hear about this... w3schools is the best for starters ... it's like fast food info :) i really don't like when some1 explains a thing in 1 page when it could be done with 10 words ... Thats what i like about w3schools ... it's str8 to the point ... ofc for some advanced  and up to date info its not the best place to get infos

Answer (score 0):

Your XML syntax is fine and generates something similar as below.

```
1.01 Outdoor_outlet_seller

Product
true

124
Update

prod_sku1

A_GEN_TAX
2012-01-24T23:02:33+0000

prod_brand1
prod_descr
Sports & Outdoors
```

My guess is that something in the values returned by the $product functions that creates the problem. Try to echo the values alone to see if anything is unexpected